# Updating pivot table by id in laravel

Tags: laravel, pivot-table, updatemodel

```
bookmaker table
id
name


bookmaker_user table
id 
account_name
bookmaker_id
user_id


user table
id
name

User Model :
public function bookmakers(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Bookmaker', 'bookmaker_user', 'user_id', 'bookmaker_id')
            ->withPivot('id', 'accountname')->withTimestamps();
}


BookmakerController.php
public function update($id)
{
            $bookname = Input::get('booknamemodifselect');
            $accountname = Input::get('accountnamemodifinput');
            $bankrollinvested = Input::get('bankrollinvestedmodifinput');
            $bonus = Input::get('bonusmodifinput');
            $bankrollamount = Input::get('bankrollamountmodifinput');

            $bookmodif = DB::table('bookmakers')->where('name', $bookname)->first();


            $bookmaker = $this->user->bookmakers()->where('bookmaker_user.id','=',$id)->first();
            $bookmaker->pivot->bookmaker_id = $bookmodif->id;
            $bookmaker->pivot->save();
    }
```

$id is the id of the account

$this->user is the user authentified.

I want to update the bookmaker for an account by his id (by account id I mean) that belongs to the user auth. Because the user auth have multiple entries with the same bookmaker but different account name.
It says 'Trying to get property of non-object'.

Comment: On which line exactly do you get the "Trying to get property of non-object" error?

Comment: $bookmaker->pivot->bookmaker_id = $bookmodif->id;

Comment: Could you check if it really finds a bookmaker? I suppose `$bookmodif` is null?

Comment: it really find a bookmaker but now it shows 'Trying to get property of non-object' when i change something... so weird

Comment: Ok this is not really about your problem, but don't you think the bookmaker_user table is a bit more than just a pivot table. I think it should get its own Model (`Account`) maybe.
You are saying you have multiple records in the table that have the same user_id and bookmaker_id. Normally that shouldn't be the case with a many to many relationship

Comment: that's what i thought too

Comment: I would go for it. If you need some help, let me know

Comment: i find it in a successfull way but when i do a save() it doesn't save in my mysql db.

Comment: Yes I had that too when I tried it locally. If you wanna stay with this db setup for the moment I suggest you us the Fluent Query Builder to directly update it. Give me a few minutes, I'll write up a proper answer ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To sum up the comments below the question, it isn't a very common database design. And this also means, that it would probably be a good idea to change that. By converting the `bookmaker_user` pivot table into a full grown table with its own model class. Reasons for that are:

- Multiple records that belong to the same user and bookmaker (many-to-many should only have one)
- Additional data stored in the pivot table (while normally okay, it adds to the first point)
- Easier handling of changes (e.g. changing the bookmaker of an account)

But that's not really the problem the question poses so here's that:

I tried it out locally and I didn't get any errors, but I wouldn't save to the database.
It seems to be some kind of bug or unexpected behavior. However a workaround is using the Query Builder.
In my opinion its even more elegant for this case...

```
$bookmodif = DB::table('bookmakers')->where('name', $bookname)->first();

if($bookmodif !== null){  // just to make sure the bookmaker exists
    DB::table('bookmaker_user')
        ->where('id', $id)
        ->update(array('bookmaker_id' => $bookmodif->id);
}
```

Comment: it works thanks for your answer! i can't vote up i dont have 15 reputation, can someone votes up please!

Comment: "many-to-many should only have one"... what part of 'many-to-many' means 'one'?

Answer (score 0):

I've been dealing with this. You can do:

```
$user = $this->user->bookmakers()->having('pivot_id', $myPivotId)->first(); 
echo $user->pivot->bookmaker_id; // bookmaker_id of the pivot row with id $myPivotId
```